# How to do gui transplantation in Java?

Tags: java, linux, qt, user-interface, fltk

I have a Qt(c++) and FLTK (lua) GUI running. And i have Java AWT/Swing GUI running, side by side in a Desktop.

How can i now inject the Qt/FLTK GUI window A-Z to my JAva Window or JWindow? So that it becomes such tree:

```
JWindow
|_ Third party (Qt/FLTK windows)
   |_ Button pressed on QT triggers its own c++ functions
   |_ Button pressed on FLTK triggers its own lua functions
|
|_ Watching them side by side in one main window (java)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this in AWT/Swing.

Since you're on Linux, you *might* be able to do something like this using [XEmbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEmbed).